# How does the background change every n seconds?

Tags: javascript

he requestAnimationFrame function, updates the canvas too fast, so, I can not do what I want. What do I want ? I want to change the background color of the canvas, every 2 seconds, but the problem is that I am cleaning the canvas in each frame. What I can do ?

```js
(function(d, w) {

    var canvas = d.getElementsByTagName("CANVAS")[0],
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var x = 0,
        y = 0,
        speedX = .9;
    update(x, y, speedX);

    function update(x, y, speedX) {
        var color = "";
        setTimeout(function() { // Here i try set the color each 2s
            color = randomColor(); // Need the color here
        }, 2000);
        ctx.fillStyle = color; // here paint the background
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // paint
        x += speedX;
        box(x, y, speedX);
        requestAnimationFrame(function() { // animation frame
            update(x, y, speedX);
        });
    }

    function box(x, y, speedX) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
        ctx.fillRect(+x, +y, 50, 50);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function randomColor() {
        for (var i = 0, str = "", hex = "0123456789ABCDEF",
                random, max = hex.length; i < 6; i++, random =
            Math.floor(Math.random() * max), str += hex[random]);

        return "#" + str;
    }


})(document, window);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Perhaps look into game loops, and how to adjust the framerate with delta timing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you are initializing `color` timeout inside `update` which is being fired every second. So essentially, you are creating a new timeout every millisecond but this value is never been accepted as the moment `color` is updated, you reset its value to `""`. Move the code to change background outside and use `setInterval` instead. So the process of creation of timers and updation of color is separate section and you will not override it in recursion.

Following is a sample

```js
(function(d, w) {

  var canvas = d.getElementsByTagName("CANVAS")[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  var x = 0,
    y = 0,
    speedX = .9;
  update(x, y, speedX);
  var color = randomColor();
  setInterval(function() { // Here i try set the color each 2s
    color = randomColor(); // Need the color here
  }, 2000);

  function update(x, y, speedX) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() { // animation frame
      ctx.fillStyle = color; // here paint the background
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // paint
      x += speedX;
      box(x, y, speedX);
      update(x, y, speedX);
    });
  }

  function box(x, y, speedX) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillRect(+x, +y, 50, 50);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function randomColor() {
    for (var i = 0, str = "", hex = "0123456789ABCDEF",
        random, max = hex.length; i < 6; i++, random =
      Math.floor(Math.random() * max), str += hex[random]);

    return "#" + str;
  }


})(document, window);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```